# How to send post request to Firebase function?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, paypal, google-cloud-functions

I created a Firebase function to payout a driver through PayPal.

**index.js from  firebase-function**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

paypal.configure({
    mode: 'sandbox',
    client_id: functions.config().paypal.client_id,
    client_secret: functions.config().paypal.client_secret
})

exports.newRequest = functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    var requestSnapshot = snapshot.val();
    var price  = snapshot.child('price').val();
    var pushId = context.params.pushId;

    return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).child('price').set(price);
 });


function getPayoutsPending(uid) {
    return admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history').once('value').then((snap) => {
        if(snap === null){
            throw new Error("profile doesn't exist");
        }
        var array = [];
        if(snap.hasChildren()){
            snap.forEach(element => {
                if (element.val() === true) {
                    array.push(element.key);
                }
            });
        }
        return array;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return console.error(error);
    });
}

function getPayoutsAmount(array) {
    return admin.database().ref('history').once('value').then((snap) => {
        var value = 0.0;
        if(snap.hasChildren()){
            snap.forEach(element => {
                if(array.indexOf(element.key) > -1) {
                        if(element.child('price').val() !== null){
                            value += element.child('price').val();
                        }
                }
            });
            return value;
        }
        return value;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return console.error(error);
    });
}

function updatePaymentsPending(uid, paymentId) {
    return admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history').once('value').then((snap) => {
        if(snap === null){
            throw new Error("profile doesn't exist");
        }

        if(snap.hasChildren()){
            snap.forEach(element => {
                if(element.val() === true) {
                    admin.database().ref('Users/Drivers/' + uid + '/history/' + element.key).set( {
                        timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                        paymentId: paymentId
                    });
                    admin.database().ref('history/' + element.key + '/driverPaidOut').set(true);
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }).catch((error) => {
        return console.error(error);
    });
}

exports.payout = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    return getPayoutsPending(request.body.uid)
        .then(array => getPayoutsAmount(array))
        .then(value => {
            var valueTrunc = parseFloat(Math.round((value * 0.75) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            const sender_batch_id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(9);
            const sync_mode = 'false';
            const payReq = JSON.stringify({
                sender_batch_header: {
                    sender_batch_id: sender_batch_id,
                    email_subject: "You have a payment"
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        recipient_type: "EMAIL",
                        amount: {
                            value: valueTrunc,
                            currency: "CAD"
                        },
                        receiver: request.body.email,
                        note: "Thank you.",
                        sender_item_id: "Payment"
                    }
                ]
            });

            return paypal.payout.create(payReq, sync_mode, (error, payout) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.warn(error.response);
                    response.status('500').end();
                    throw error;
                }
                console.info("payout created");
                console.info(payout);
                return updatePaymentsPending(request.body.uid, sender_batch_id)
            });
        }).then(() => {
            response.status('200').end();
            return null;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
});
```

The code that I used in Android works fine but with the code I have in iOS, its not working right.

The code in IOS, as per index.js file, after putting the driver's email in the textfield and when PAYOUT button is pressed, it does the following:

- it adds the payment ID and Timestamp the the users/drivers and users/riders
- it adds 'driverPaidOut = true' to the history db
- it creates, in firebase functions logs a "payout created"

But what it doesn't do, is make it to PayPal and create a notification to the driver's email.

As you can see, there are two variables the index.js file requires: the 'uid' and the 'email' of the driver

**Android code, that works:**

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    // in json - we need variables for the hardcoded uid and Email
    JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();

    try {
        postData.put("uid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        postData.put("email", mPayoutEmail.getText().toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Request body ...
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postData.toString());

    // Build Request ...
    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Your Token")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            // something went wrong right off the bat
            progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            // response successful ....
            // refers to response.status('200') or ('500')
            int responseCode = response.code();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                switch(responseCode) {
                    case 200:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Payout Successful!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        break;

                    case 500:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Error: no payout available", Snackbar
                                        .LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    default:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                                "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }

            } else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout),
                        "Error: couldn't complete the transaction",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

**iOS code, not working:**

```
let email = txtPayoutEmail.text!
    let userId = self.uid!

    let parameters = "uid=\(userId)&email=\(email)"
    let url = "https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Your Token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "cache-control")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    print("URL : \(request)")

    request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        }

        do {
            let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
            print(response!)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

I have tried different (practically every one on the net) examples online whether it be Alamofire or not and nothing seems to work.

### Edit - response from Sahil Manchanda

getting httpResponse:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000132620> { URL: https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Content-Length" =     (
    0
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/html"
);
Date =     (
    "Mon, 17 Dec 2018 07:44:57 GMT"
);
Server =     (
    "Google Frontend"
);
"alt-svc" =     (
    "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"44,43,39,35\""
);
"function-execution-id" =     (
    wspeunpt1umy
);
"x-cloud-trace-context" =     (
    "a2444e17fb874853489b56684de9fe10;o=1"
);
"x-powered-by" =     (
    Express
);
} })
```

### Edit #2 - still not working

Sahil Manchanda was very helpful but not an expert on the backend of Firebase.

After making a few corrections in the code, debugging the index.js, for some reason it is not working on the server end.

My new code:

```
let email = txtPayoutEmail.text!

    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Authorization" : "Bearer \(token)"
    ]

    let body = ["uid": uid, "email": email]

    let postData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")! as URL,  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse!)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
```

When running app, this is what is seen in Firebase functions, it seems good, but doesn't get to PayPal like it does in the Android app?

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you are missing is JSON string in your iOS code. in Android you are using JSONObject then convert it to String. whereas in your iOS, this conversion is missing. Try below code. see if its working or not. I've made some adjustments which should satisfy your need.

```
import Foundation

let headers = [
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
  "Authorization" : "your token"
]
let parameters = [
  "email": "abc@abc.com",
  "uid": "12"
] as [String : Any]

let postData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://us-central1-ryyde-sj.cloudfunctions.net/payout")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: I used your code above and I posted the response - see EDIT

Comment: @LizG The response code is 200, try printing the request variable in your index.js and see if its getting there or not

Comment: not sure what you mean, I am very very. new at this.

Comment: @LizG  I mean try to send UID and email back in response.

Comment: you mean replace the let parameters = [
  "email": "abc@abc.com",
  "uid": "12" with the actual variables like let parameters = [
  "email": email,
  "uid": userId ?

Comment: Yes and also replace the token

Comment: same result as before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185342/discussion-between-sahil-manchanda-and-lizg).

Comment: see the discussion in the room sahil